# Replace the comma's with double quotes but not the comma which are already enclosed in double quotes

Tags: powershell

What i tried is

`import-csv C:\file.csv | export-csv C:\file2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`

The above code works but is there any way to replace it in the same file?

Example :
Content in csv - text,"text with a,comma",sample

output should be -  "text","text with a,comma","sample"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `Import-Csv` part in brackets so that cmdlet will be finished with the file and you can overwrite the same:

```
(Import-Csv -Path 'C:\file.csv') | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>P.S. from the question it isn't clear if the CSV file has headers. If not, use the `-Header` parameter on `Import-Csv`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way other than the code i mentioned to replace the comma's. My code is taking some time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import-csv C:\file.csv | export-csv C:\file2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
Get-Content C:\file2.csv | set-content C:\file.csv
Remove-Item C:\file2.csv
```